# How do I receive properly children component state trigged by father component onClick?

Tags: reactjs

I am confused about a question and I hope you can help me.

So I have this code, and I want to get the state of the Cards (children components) by clicking the button on the father Component. I have created a callback function and through a father's state "flag" it  can trigger the children, calling this callback by an If check on their escope.

The problem is that if I use a local var as "var cloned" to keep this data, they will stay there in just one Re-render call, beeing lost later, and the re-render is called before cloned data is updated with the proper card values, rendering the cards with old values. If I use a state (to keep it safe through re-renders) and probably be able to render the cards with the new values, I have a "Maximum update depth exceeded" (the code that is commented inside the callback function "catchInfo").

The main purpose is to have this cards beeing updated (and shown if it was modified or not) and after clicking the button have my data all updated (and possibly later do some post request and something). But with this click, beyond change the data it should display the updated cards.

I am a beginner React developer and If you can help me I really would appreciate! Thanks!

Here are the code:

Father Component:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    "card#1": {
      nome: "Rodrigo",
      idade: 23,
      altura: 1.86,
    },
    "card#2": {
      nome: "Julia",
      idade: 21,
      altura: 1.7,
    },
    "card#3": {
      nome: "Letícia",
      idade: 23,
      altura: 1.65,
    },
    "card#4": {
      nome: "Natasha",
      idade: 22,
      altura: 1.75,
    },
    "card#5": {
      nome: "Vivian",
      idade: 23,
      altura: 1.73,
    },
  });

  var cloned = cloneDeep(data);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  const catchInfo = (id, nome, idade) => {
    // setData((oldData) => {
    //   return {
    //     ...oldData,
    //     [`card#${id + 1}`]: { ...oldData[`card#${id + 1}`], nome, idade },
    //   };
    // });
    cloned = {
      ...cloned,
      [`card#${id + 1}`]: { ...cloned[`card#${id + 1}`], nome, idade },
    };
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{ padding: "40px", textAlign: "center", background: "#f0f0f0" }}
    >
      <h1>React</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setFlag(true);
        }}
      >
        Pegar Info
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(cloned);
        }}
      >
        Ver Cloned
      </button>

      <div
        style={{
          padding: "40px",
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
        }}
      >
        {Object.entries(cloned).map(([key, value], i) => {
          return (
            <Card
              {...value}
              key={key}
              i={i}
              catchInfo={catchInfo}
              flag={flag}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child Component:

```
const Card = (props) => {
  const { nome, idade, altura, catchInfo, i, flag } = props;

  const [name, setName] = useState(nome);
  const [age, setAge] = useState(idade);
  const [isModified, setIsModified] = useState(false);

  if (flag) {
    catchInfo(i, name, age);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (name !== nome || age !== idade) setIsModified(true);
    else setIsModified(false);
  }, [name, age]);

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", width: "30%", margin: "40px" }}>
      <h3>
        {isModified && "*"}Nome: {nome}
      </h3>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <p>Idade: {idade} anos</p>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={age}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setAge(parseInt(e.target.value));
        }}
      />
      <p>Altura: {altura} metros</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What you exactly want to achieve? Maybe I can suggest you some other way to do this.

Comment: The main purpose is to have an updatable list of cards, where I can edit the info previously displayed and change this info, adding to database for instance (all the cards who were modified) and after that, re-render the whole list of cards with the updated values (without having to make a get request again, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have something like this.

**Parent**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

export default function App() {
  const [modified, setModified] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    "card#1": {
      nome: "Rodrigo",
      idade: 23,
      altura: 1.86
    },
    "card#2": {
      nome: "Julia",
      idade: 21,
      altura: 1.7
    },
    "card#3": {
      nome: "Letícia",
      idade: 23,
      altura: 1.65
    },
    "card#4": {
      nome: "Natasha",
      idade: 22,
      altura: 1.75
    },
    "card#5": {
      nome: "Vivian",
      idade: 23,
      altura: 1.73
    }
  });

  const handleValues = (id, property, value) => {
    setModified((prev) => [...prev, id]);
    setData((prev) => {
      prev[id][property] = value;
      return prev;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{ padding: "40px", textAlign: "center", background: "#f0f0f0" }}
    >
      <h1>React</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setModified([])}>Pegar Info</button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(data);
        }}
      >
        Ver Cloned
      </button>

      <div
        style={{
          padding: "40px",
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap"
        }}
      >
        {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
          return (
            <Card
              {...value}
              key={key}
              id={key}
              handleValues={handleValues}
              isModified={modified.includes(key)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Card = (props) => {
  const { nome, idade, altura, handleValues, id, isModified } = props;
  const [originalNome, setOriginalNome] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isModified && nome !== originalNome) setOriginalNome(nome);
  }, [isModified]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOriginalNome(nome);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", width: "30%", margin: "40px" }}>
      <h3>
        {isModified && "*"}Nome: {originalNome}
      </h3>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={nome}
        onChange={(e) => handleValues(id, "nome", e.target.value)}
      />
      <p>Idade: {idade} anos</p>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={idade}
        onChange={(e) => handleValues(id, "idade", parseInt(e.target.value))}
      />
      <p>Altura: {altura} metros</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: I understood the code and it does work. However, since I want to reproduce that concept in a bigger cenario (lot more data and bigger forms on cards) I was trying to avoid setting father's state on form changes (to much re-render of all child components) and just do so with the button clicked. For my real case application it works but I believe it won't be performatic at all.

Comment: You can do it by providing a button in Card to pass the data to the parent.

Comment: I know, but it is a behaviour I was trying to avoid.